# How to embed dynamic URLs of Images in HTML content stored in DB?

Tags: php, html, database, image, dynamic

I store a lot of `HTML` contents in `DB`
That i have print in many dynamic pages
For example

```
// returned from DB
$contentHTML = 
'
    <h1>Photo Number 1</h1>
    <p>description1</p>
    <p><img src="../images/1.jpg"/></p>
    <h1>Photo Number 2</h1>
    <p>description2</p>
    <p><img src="../images/2.jpg"/></p>
';
// Print HTML content
echo $contentHTML;
```

My problem is that
My HTML code contain `images URLs`
And my current images folder (images) in application server

*But in the future* its expected to change this folder

- To be in another folder
- To be in another server

*So it will be a very complex and hard task to replace all images URLs*

Then
Any idea or trick for
How to embed dynamic URLs of Images in HTML content stored in DB
Or how make it configurable ?

Comment: Do you really have to store it as HTML? If it's only photos, description etc you should probably store them in a normal manner. If you absolutely have to then perhaps you can store them in such a way `<img src="{|imgpath|}/images/2.jpg" />` and then replace `{|imgpath|}` with the current path in the PHP script.

Comment: @Colandus exactly correct answer ... you can also check the detailed steps in Joraid anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually make an ad-hoc script for this kind of scenarios.

**Step 1:**

Replace all hard links with dynamic known variable.

```
../images/ to [[PUBLIC_PATH]][[IMG_DIR]]
```

**Step 2:**

Before use, replace the actual server address and image dir with variable you have added.

E.g.

```
contentHTML  = NDatabase::getAssoc("select myField from myTable");//yada yada      
$contentHTML = 
'
    <h1>Photo Number 1</h1>
    <p>description1</p>
    <p><img src="[[PUBLIC_PATH]][[IMG_DIR]]/1.jpg"/></p>
    <h1>Photo Number 2</h1>
    <p>description2</p>
    <p><img src="[[PUBLIC_PATH]][[IMG_DIR]]/2.jpg"/></p>
';

$myNewServerPath = "http://www.mysite.come/en/";
$myPublicFolder = "{myNewServerPath}public/";
$myImgDir = "img"



 $newContent = str_replace(array("[[PUBLIC_PATH]]","[[IMG_DIR]]") ,  array($myPublicFolder,$myImgDir )  ,$contentHTML  )
```

After that you can either update your DB or just use the code as it's.

Personally, I have a file full of list of constants dynamically generated to to get the site name, site URL, site sub folders etc.

```
define("CURR_PATH","http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/");//
```

Guess you got the idea.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite URLs to point to the new location.

eg:

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ new-images-folder/$1 [NC,L]
```